# Why does <*> of the Const instance accept two non-functional values?

Tags: haskell, applicative

```
(<*>) :: Applicative f => f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
Const :: a -> Const a b
Monoid m => Applicative (Const * m)

Const "a" <*> Const "b" -- yields Const "ab"
Const a <*> Const a = Const a <> Const a
```

I guess this behavior must have something to do with the fact that `Const` is a binary type constructor, where `b` is never touched (phantom type). But then again I don't understand `Const * m`, because `a` (and `*` respectively) seems to be discarded in this case.

Comment: How did you produce the output `Monoid m => Applicative (Const * m)` ?

Comment: merely copied it from [Hackage](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html#v:Const)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First if `m` has a `Monoid` instance, then `Const m` has a `Applicative` instance. But `Const m` is still a type constructor, so the type of `<*>`
for `Applicative (Const m)` reads

```
     (<*>) :: Const m (a -> b) -> Const m a -> Const m b
```

Now let apply this to `Const "a"` and `Const "b"`:

`Const "a"` is of type `Const String b`. So here the type variable `m` from above assumes the type `String`. The value is still polymorphic with respect to `b` and as it doesn't contain a concrete value of that type, the type can still be anything.

In the expression `Const "a" <*> Const "b"` the polymorphic value `Const "a"` will be forced to be of type `Const String (a->b)` and the polymorphic value `Const "b"` will be forced to be of type `Const String a`.

So there really is a type with a function type inside on the left side, just the concrete value doesn't contain a function, like with value `Nothing` of type `Maybe (Int -> Int)`.

PS.: I don't know where the `*` comes from in `Monoid m => Applicative (Const * m)`. If I type

```
    :info Const
```

in ghci, I get the line

```
    instance Monoid m => Applicative (Const m)
```

Comment: Ah OK, this `Const * m` confused me. `Const m` is still polymorphic and since the second type variable is never touched, it can be everything, including a function. This makes perfect sense for a constant on the type level. magnificent!

Comment: Hackage has some weirdness (I think with `PolyKinds` turned on?) where it sometimes displays the kind parameters explicitly like this. `Const * m` I think might be because the second type parameter is polykinded (since it's phantom), but to instantiate `Applicative` `Const m` needs to be `* -> *`, hence the kind parameter to `Const` (the kind of the type parameter that hasn't been filled yet) needs to be given as `*`. So the `m` is the *first* type parameter, and the `*` is a kind parameter that usually is left implicit, so you're not used to setting it. Something like that, anyway.